# Getting Error When use Date to Search

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, date

```
        cmdDateReceivingStock = new SqlCommand("Select Distinct Date FROM 
        OrderDetails WHERE item_Received ='No'", conStock);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdDateReceivingStock);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        ddlOrderDate.DataTextFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}";
        ddlOrderDate.DataSource = ds;
        ddlOrderDate.DataTextField = "Date";
        ddlOrderDate.DataBind();
```

After I success convert the date into dropdownlist,but I getting this error"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." when I use the date to retrieve data from database.

Comment: There is a format field on the gridview to set your format, other way is to set it when you make the select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SELECT statement is fine, you have to modify the date format in your ddl:

```
ddlOrderDate.DataTextFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
ddlOrderDate.DataTextFormatString = "{yyyy-MM-dd}";
```

This will format the date for you and remove the zeros

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your sql query.

```
 cmdDateReceivingStock = new SqlCommand("Select Distinct CONVERT(VARCHAR,Date,103) FROM 
        OrderDetails WHERE item_Received ='No'", conStock);
```

Additional reading: To get different date and datetime formats refer this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way in sql query

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126)
```

Change your query with  using **DATE_FORMAT()**

```
cmdDateReceivingStock = new SqlCommand("Select Distinct DATE_FORMAT(Date , '%d/%m/%Y') FROM 
        OrderDetails WHERE item_Received ='No'", conStock);
```

for more [date formating](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx)

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126) this also need put in

Comment: can you post your current select query . please past my query instead of your query and remove ddlOrderDate.DataTextFormatString